# Check if a value in a list is equal to some number

Tags: python

I've got a list of data:

```
[[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

And I'm trying to check if any of the individual numers is equal to 3, and if so return which element, so list[0],list[3] e.t.c within the original list contains this value 3.

I've gotten as far as:

```
for i in range(0, len(gcounter_selection)):
  for x in range(0,len(gcounter_selection)):
    if any(x) in gcounter_selection[i][x]==3:
      print(i)
```

My list is called gcounter_selection by the way.

But I'm getting a type error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

I've tried using a generator expression but I couldnt get that to work either.

Comment: Python lists are 0 indexed, so you probably mean: list[0],list[3] in your example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for list comprehensions:

```
value = 3
lst = [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
items = [x for x in lst if value in x]
print(items)
#[[0, 3], [3, 0]]
```

To get elements' positions instead of just elements, add `enumerate`:

```
indexes = [n for n, x in enumerate(lst) if value in x]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This works perfectly, but how would I modify if I lst element? i.e  return "lst[1], lst[4]"

Comment: Okay I've just tried your solution to get the position but it only returns : [0, 3], so I think its checking the second digit only in the list.

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman: it returns `[0,3]` because there are two elements in your list that contain "3" - the 0th and the 3rd elements.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed version of your original

```
gcounter_selection = [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]

for i in range(0, len(gcounter_selection)):
    if any(x == 3 for x in gcounter_selection[i]):
        print(i)
```

However this can be simplified to

```
for i, x in enumerate(gcounter_selection):
    if any(y == 3 for y in x):
        print(i)
```

And there is no need for `any` in this case, just check with `in`

```
for i, x in enumerate(gcounter_selection):
    if 3 in x:
        print(i)
```